# Auto Zoom when change portrait to landscape in webview >19

Tags: android

webview zoom automatically when change orientation. 
i want webview as normal screen no matter if it scrolling just want zoom out webview.
how to resolve this.

i played with initialscaling but no changes.

i have created custom webview

```
 package com.myapp.app;

 import android.content.Context;

 import android.util.AttributeSet;

 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class YourCustomWebView extends WebView {


  public YourCustomWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
  }

public YourCustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public YourCustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int   defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {  

    public int scrollmiddle(){

    int returnval=this.computeHorizontalScrollRange();
    this.scrollTo((returnval/4) + 100, this.getScrollY());

    return returnval;
}
}
```

and java file like this.

```
@Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  mWebView.saveState(outState);
 }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
```

in onCreate method.

```
mWebView = (YourCustomWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

if(savedInstanceState != null){
          mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
          mWebView.setInitialScale(0);

          webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    }else{
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
             webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
         }

         webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

         MyWebChromeClient chromeclient=new MyWebChromeClient();
         mWebView.setWebChromeClient(chromeclient);
         MyWebViewClient client = new MyWebViewClient();
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(client);

         mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");


         mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.urlhome));

    }
```

here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

 <com.myapp.app.YourCustomWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

i have try many way but not success.

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the following to your HTML:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

and to your CSS:

`html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}`

Taken from [this post](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/avoiding-landscape-zoom-in-effect-on-mobile) (and the comments).

Comment: is it android not web dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

or in manifest.xml for every activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: Dear thanks for your answer, but it not working. problem as it is.

Comment: check now .. may b it can help you